# crystal report two copies each page

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

Using Crystal Reports with Visual Studio 10 and I want to print a report big half-sheet A4 twice on the same page. I tried to insert two identical subreport,  but one subreport prints empty. Some advice? Other way? Thank you.

Comment: Where did you place the sub reports

Comment: I tried in all sections

Comment: if sub reports are identical then there is no chance that one sub report prints data and other doesn't... check the database connection in second sub report.

Comment: I did the following:
I created a new report.
I added two subreport with the original report
this is the result:
http://www.infoleo.it/temp/testprint.png